# How to query GroupMember as a subquery of User in soql?

Tags: apex, soql, salesforcedx

I want to fetch GroupMember associate with each user and try the below SOQL query which doesn't work

```
SELECT Id, (Select Id from Groups) FROM User
```

But when I try the same thing with PermissionSetAssignment it works, below is the SOQL that I use

```
SELECT Id, (Select permissionsetGroup.Id from PermissionSetAssignments) FROM User
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, this relationship doesn't have a name, so you can't perform a subquery that will work.

```
for(ChildRelationship r: sObjectType.User.getChildRelationships()) {
    String rn = r.getRelationshipName();
    if(r.getChildSObject() == GroupMember.sobjectType) {
        System.debug(rn); // null
    }
}
```

You need to instead query from the GroupMember object instead:

```
SELECT GroupId, UserOrGroupId FROM GroupMember
```

Comment: Will the polymorphic nature of the `UserOrGroupId` field cause issues here?

Comment: @PhilW Shouldn't cause any problems, it's just that the code will have to determine which groups a user belongs to, possibly recursively.